# angular.js "paginate" array items with left right buttons

Tags: angularjs

I have an array with 100 items.

I want to show 5 items at a time and have a button `<` left and `>` right.

When the right button is clicked, I show the next 5 items from array (from 6 - 11) and so forth. When arrive at the end of array show the last 5 or less items and the right button is disabled. When you are at the beginning of the array, the left button is disabled and show the first 5 or less items.

Here is my attempt: http://plnkr.co/edit/2zbTKQSRGtqdfchCeaLK?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in to Angular Datatables to display the data?

http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/

Answer (score 0):

Try UI bootstrap Pagination component. It will serve your purpose.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination

Comment: I am trying to use the pager functionality from  ui bootstrap. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pager. I set up an example using it but I cannot make it work. Here it is: http://plnkr.co/edit/2zbTKQSRGtqdfchCeaLK?p=preview